# where to put log4j.properties in java gradle web application on eclipse

Tags: log4j, gradle, slf4j

I am making a simple web application using Gradle. I am using slf4j and log4j as loggers, I added 3 jars using gradle.build file to work with slf4j. I went through the some gradle and slf4j tutorials and still I could not find and answer that where to put log4j.properties in gradle project. Can any body help me for that ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`log4j.properties` is typically read from the web app's class path, and as such you would put it into `src/main/resources`.

Comment: should I have to change my build.gradle other than adding slf4j,log4j and slf4j-log4j12? I added log4j.properties file to src/main/java . Is it wrong ? And Do I have to make any changes in web.xml config ?

Comment: Which Jars to add depends on how you use log4j. `src/main/java` is wrong. No changes to `web.xml` are required.

Comment: slf4j-api.jar ect...   although I added the log4j.properties, it not goes to war file in tomcat. I think I have to write it in main gradle.build file. Am I correct ? Can you help me to add that code to gradle.build ?

Comment: I you have `apply plugin: 'war'` in the build script, and put the `log4j.properties` file into `src/main/resources`, you should find it under `classes/log4j.properties` in the War.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
 //import org.slf4j.Logger;

//import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log4jTest {

//Slf4J
//final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jTest.class);


//Log4J
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Log4jTest.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("Logging with Log 4J starts");

    Log4jTest obj = new Log4jTest();

    try{
        obj.divide();
    }catch(ArithmeticException ex){
        logger.error("Sorry, something wrong!", ex);
    }


}

private void divide(){

    int i = 10 /0;

}

}
```

** Log4J property file**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p  %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Rirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=E:\\Logging\\log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

** Dependency for build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.18'
}
```